# Automate Calendar event with attachment using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

My intention are to create calendar event based on the date with attachment. I get an error

> HttpResponseException: Response Code: 404. Message: Not Found. (line
>   40, file "Code")

Line 40 is

```
var resp = Calendar.Events.insert(eventObj, calendarId, {'supportsAttachments': true})
```

I just can't figure out what am I doing wrong. I have 50 events to create and hoping I can automate it. Much appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

```
function createNewEvent() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendarId = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('');
    var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
    var count = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:F"+lr+"").getValues();
    var fileId = '';

    for (var x = 0; x < count.length; x++) {
        var shift = count[x];
        var daysent = shift[3];

        if (daysent == 0) {
            var summary = shift[0];
            var startTime = shift[1];
            var endTime = shift[2];
            var guests = shift[4];
            var description = shift[5];
            var sendInvites = true;
            var eventObj = {
                summary: summary,
                startTime: startTime,
                endTime: endTime,
                description: description,
                guests: guests,
                sendInvites: sendInvites,
                attachments: [{
                    'fileUrl': 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + fileId,
                    'title': 'Recording a Presentation ',
                }]
            };

            var resp = Calendar.Events.insert(eventObj, calendarId, {'supportsAttachments': true});
            Logger.log(resp); // Check out the response in the logs!`
```

Comment: Could you share a spreadsheet with some example data please?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error:

> HttpResponseException: Response Code: 404. Message: Not Found. (line
>   40, file "Code")

Due to you are passing to the `insert` method, a *calendar id* that doesn't exist or that you don't access to it. You can check more [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#404_not_found)  .